# Python asyncio double await

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio

For some reason I need to write a double `await`, but I don't exactly know why. Can someone explain this to me?

I've created a small example of the issue I ran into.

```py
import asyncio
from random import randint

async def work():
    return randint(1, 100)

async def page():
    return asyncio.gather(*[
        work()
        for _ in range(10)
    ])

async def run():
    results = await (await page())
    return max(list(results))

result = asyncio.run(run())
```

It is the line `results = await (await page())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To actually *execute* awaitable objects you need to `await` on them.

Your `page` here is coroutine function, when called, it returns a coroutine which *is* an awaitable object!

When you say `await page()`, you're running the body of it. after execution it gives you(`return`) another awaitable object which is the result of calling `asyncio.gather()`. So you need to `await` on that too. That's why you need two `await`.

If you don't you'd see:

```
RuntimeError: await wasn't used with future
```

You could do this nested await expression inside the calling coroutine:

```py
import asyncio
from random import randint


async def work():
    return randint(1, 100)


async def page():
    return await asyncio.gather(*[work() for _ in range(10)])


async def run():
    results = await page()
    return max(list(results))


result = asyncio.run(run())
print(result)
```